# jQuery carousel duplicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a bootstrap template, which has jQuery carousel in it. I am trying to multiply it, but when I copy the whole div and paste it, the controls are applying to the original one.

How can I do that?

I can't post the jQuery js, because it is too large.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="about"  class="about">
      <div class="row">
     
      <div class="col-sm-5 wowload fadeInLeft">
      <div class="spacer test2"><h4><i class="fa fa-code"></i>hi</h4><hr>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley.</p>
      </div>
      </div>

       <div class="col-sm-7 wowload fadeInRight">
        <div id="carousel-works" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
         <div class="item active"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive"></div>
         <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive"></div>
         <div class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>    
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-works" role="button" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-works" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Are the IDs are unique when you copy and paste the markup for the carousel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="carousel-works" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
```

When you copy the carousel change the id to something else than carousel-works

Also the controls "href"`to the new ID

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-works" role="button" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-left"></i></a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-works" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-right"></i></a>
```

Something like this may be

```
<div class="col-sm-7 wowload fadeInRight">
        <div id="carousel-works2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
         <div class="item active"><img src="images/portfolio/4.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
         <div class="item"><img src="images/portfolio/5.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
         <div class="item"><img src="images/portfolio/6.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>    
        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-works2" role="button" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-works2" role="button" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```